# React fetch gets response from callback only if all requests are finished

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I'm using react fetch to poll GET api request periodically every 5 second. First 8 requests work properly meaning I get response for each request immediately, but then the problem came when there are more api requests waiting in queue and I got the message "CAUTION: request is not finished yet". I got the response only if all the request are finished (seems it waits for all the requests to finish then return the response in the callback).

How can I get the response of each request immediately without waiting for all the requests to finish?

```
fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response != null) {
             // Got the response only if all requests are finished
            this.setState({
                ...
            })
        }
    })
}
```

MORE INFO, I'm using Spring Boot as API server, GET endpoint.

Comment: have you tried setTimeout ?

Comment: @SnehalDangroshiya I tried to set timeout as per your suggestion but it still does not work. Seems it is the problem after 8 requests are sent then the subsequent requests are waited until the last request is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The fetch call returns a promise. So, you should not immediately call another function but rather provide a function which should be called when the promise resolves successfully.

Comment: Could you please give more details? From the given code, I set state the in the callback once promise object is resolved successfully.

Comment: Try this if this works

``` lang-js
fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
        this.setState({

         })
        return response.json();
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not working... my react fetch can print response for only the first 8 requests. The next requests are not going to the spring boot api while I see the requests in the Chrome DevTools "request is not finished yet".

Comment: oh I got it resolved. I noticed that there are two poll methods() which call two end points every 5 second at the same time. I remove one poll method then it worked.